# How to convert '1+2' into an int in python

Tags: python, string, integer, int

For example if i have:

```
x = '12'
print(int(x))
```

would turn `x` into an integer from a string.

What if I have:

```
x = '1+2'
```

And I want 3 as my output, how would I go about it since `+` cannot be converted into an int directly?

Comment: `eval(x)` will give 3. Did you even try searching first?

Answer (score 3):

Use `literal_eval` which is much more safer than using `eval`. `literal_eval` safely evaluates an expression node or a string containing a python expression.

```
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval('1+2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the eval function to accomplish this; however, it should be noted that allowing unsanitized input into the eval function can pose a significant security risk. Here's an example:

```
x = '1 + 2'
print(eval(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can use `eval`.
The usage is `eval(expression[, globals[, locals]])`.
Therefore
`eval('1+2')
3`